# \foreach and names

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, naming

I am trying to write a command to draw a cycle graph with Tikz, basically a polygon. The parameters of the command are the number #1 of vertices, and the radius #2 of the figure.

My initial thought was to draw the #1 nodes first, give them names and then connect them by an edge. The code was

```
\newcommand{\cyclegraph}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{
    \node[circle,fill=black] (n\n) at ({\n*360/#1}:#2cm) {};
}
\foreach \n in {1,...,#1-1}{
    \draw (n\n) -- (n{1+\n})
}   

\draw (n#1) -- (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Unfortunately, the code in the \foreach loop does not work. The error messages are "Package pgf Error: No shape named n{1+1} is known. \cyclegraph{7}{2}", "Package pgf Error: No shape named n{1+2} is known. \cyclegraph{7}{2}", etc. Obviously, that's a problem with the naming of the nodes. **Is there a way to fix that?**

Of course, I could rewrite the code as

```
\newcommand{\cyclegraph}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{
    \node[circle,fill=black] (n\n) at ({\n*360/#1}:#2cm) {};
}
\foreach \n in {1,...,#1-1}{
    \draw ({\n*360/#1}:#2cm) -- ({(1+\n)*360/#1}:#2cm);
}   

\draw ({0}:#2cm) -- ({360/#1}:#2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

but I think it would be cleaner to use the names of the nodes. Also, it could be useful for later figures. Any idea?

Comment: Please always add a complete example, that makes it is much easier to test the problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: it is the complete command

Comment: Ok then please copy your post in an empty (!) document and compile it. If you are successfull I will do it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand{\cyclegraph}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{
      \node[circle,fill=black] (n\n) at ({\n*360/#1}:#2cm) {};
    }
    \foreach \n[evaluate={\n as \nnext using int(mod(\n,#1)+1)}] in {1,...,#1}{
      \draw (n\n) -- (n\nnext);
    }   
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\cyclegraph{7}{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting that something simpler existed. Tikz' synthax is confusing.

Answer (score 5):

I have code very similar to this. Hacking to fit your use case you can produce:

[image]

with the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\CycleGraph[2][1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \pt [evaluate=\pt as \ang using {90+(\pt-1)*360/#2}] in {1,...,#2}
    {
        \node[circle,fill=black] (\pt) at (\ang:#1) {};
    }
    \foreach \pt [remember=\pt as \Pt (initially #2)] in {1,...,#2}
    {
        \draw (\pt)--(\Pt);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

  \CycleGraph[0.5]{3}
  \CycleGraph{4}

\end{document}
```

Notice that I have defined `\CycleGraph` to have an optional argument that gives the radius of the cycle and a mandatory argument giving the number of points.

Actually, I find the following variation on these ideas to be more useful: I define a command `\EdgeGraph` to take as arguments the number of vertices together with a comma separated list of edges. For example, `\EdgeGraph{4}{1/2,2/3,3/4,4/1}` and `\EdgeGraph{4}{1/2,2/3,3/4,4/1,1/3}` produce:

[image]

Here is the code for `\EdgeGraph`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\EdgeGraph[3][1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \pt [evaluate=\pt as \ang using {90+(\pt-1)*360/#2}] in {1,...,#2}
      {
          \node[circle,fill=black] (\pt) at (\ang:#1) {};
      }
      \foreach \x/\y in {#3} {
          \draw (\x)--(\y);
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

  \EdgeGraph{4}{1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/1}
  \EdgeGraph{4}{1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/1, 1/3}

\end{document}
```

I normally also have options to label the vertices but perhaps I am now getting too carried away!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by your second `\foreach`

```
\foreach \n in {1,...,#1-1}{
    \draw (n\n) -- (n{1+\n})
}
```

Firstly, a semicolon is missing. Secondly, calculation is not supported in node names `(n{1+\n})`. This just gives node names `(n{1+1})`, `(n{1+2})`, ... and raises an error.

Apart from more general option `evaluate` used in [@PaulGaborit's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557304/79060), here I use another option `remember` (documented near the end of pgfmanual 3.1.5b, sec. 89) to store the value of `\n` during the previous iteration in `\xn`. In the first iteration, there is no "previous one" hence I initialize `\xn` to 1. I also changed the iteration list to `2, ..., #2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\cyclegraph}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{
        \node[circle,fill=black] (n\n) at ({\n*360/#1}:#2cm) {};
    }
    \foreach \n[remember=\n as \xn(initially 1)] in {2,...,#1}{
        \draw (n\xn) -- (n\n);
    }
    \draw (n#1) -- (n1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \cyclegraph{3}{2}
\end{document}
```

Also, posting complete example (also called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) rather than complete macro definition is always preferable.