# Unexpected behavior when drawing a regular polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, polygon

I'm practicing using `pin` and `marks` on `\coordinate` and `\node`.

## Goal/Expected output

1. A regular polygon
2. parametrized by the number of sides *n*
3. with each vertex marked by a circular dot
4. and a label outside the polygon.

[image: regular polygon]

```tex
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\myR{2}
\newcommand\n{7}
\newcommand\dTheta{360/\n}
\tikzset{
  every pin edge/.style={opacity=0},
  pin distance=2pt,
  mypt/.style={circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.5pt,inner sep=-2pt},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \k in {1,...,\n} {\coordinate[mypt,pin={\dTheta*\k}:{$V_{\k}$}] (V\k) at ({\dTheta*\k}:\myR);}
\foreach \k in {2,...,\n} {\draw (V\the\numexpr\k-1) -- (V\k);}
\draw (V\n) -- (V1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Problem

Why the technique of

```
\draw (1) \foreach \n in {2,...,5} {--(\n)} --cycle;
```

in [this accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564247/126386) doesn't work when I included the styles for a vertex `mypt`?

[image: error input]

```tex
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\myR{2}
\newcommand\n{7}
\newcommand\dTheta{360/\n}
\tikzset{
  every pin edge/.style={opacity=0},
  pin distance=2pt,
  mypt/.style={circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.5pt,inner sep=-2pt},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \k in {1,...,\n} {\coordinate[mypt,pin={\dTheta*\k}:{$V_{\k}$}] (V\k) at ({\dTheta*\k}:\myR);}
\draw (V1) foreach \k in {2,...,\n} { -- (V\k)} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that if I remove `mypt`, from the above code block, then the edges will be correctly drawn.

[image: regular polygon]

Related question: [\foreach and names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557299/126386)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: thx for reminder.  i've edited my question to include that.

Comment: Remove 'dvisvgm' option and compile.

Comment: `mypt` is a node(styles for a node), so you create nodes instead of coordinates. Then you probably want `(V1.center)` and `(V\k.center)` . But why create nodes? -and why use a `pin`, when you do not want a pin?

Comment: tl;dr make sure to understand what the code does instead of just copy paste it?

Comment: @user202729 I have a basic understanding about the code.  Asking is my way of understanding the code.

Comment: @HasanBasriÇetin Thanks for suggestion.  I've figured the problem with a much simpler MWE without using labels and pins.  I'll add a self-answer soon for this.

Comment: This should provide an answer as to why it does not work with nodes but only with coordinates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75152/47927 .

Comment: I agree with Jasper. Your `mypt` style overrides the `\coordinate` alias and forces the points to become nodes which means that the bug that Jasper links to comes into force.  Also, - minor point - if you want to use `pin` without the edge then you should use `label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(this is a long comment, so I post it here)*

I never use the keys `pin` or `edge`, that are not so useful, and complexify the code in my opinion. In the code below: parameters are clear; `[parse=true]` is for labeling, and parentheses `(n)` is something undocumented in the pgfmanual.pdf, see [this Henri Menke's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616537/140722). I also change a bit the style `mypt` to the style `dot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={n=7;r=2;a=360/n;},
dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}]

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ilabel,parse=true] in {1,...,(n)}
\path (a*\i:r) coordinate (V\i) node[dot]{} +(a*\i:.4) node{$V_{\ilabel}$};     

\draw (V1) \foreach \i [parse=true] in {2,...,(n)} {--(V\i)} --cycle;   
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt},teal]
\def\n{7}
\def\r{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{360/\n}    
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
\path (\a*\i:\r) coordinate (V\i) node[dot]{} 
+(\a*\i:.4) node{$V_{\i}$}
;     
    
\draw (V1) \foreach \i in {2,...,\n} {--(V\i)} --cycle;   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Asymptote code:

[image]

```
// from Nguyen Vu Tran
unitsize(2cm);
path g=polygon(7);
draw(g);
for (int i=0;i<size(g);++i)
dot("$V_{"+string(i+1)+"}$",point(g,i),dir(point(g,i)),purple);
```

[image]

```
// from PT Sinh
unitsize(2cm);
int n=9;
pair V(int i) {return expi(2*i*pi/n + pi/n);}
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
draw(V(i)--V(i+1));
dot("$V_{"+string(i+1)+"}$",V(i),1.2V(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, minimum size=5cm](A){};
\foreach \i/\j in {1/above,2/above left, 3/left, 4/below, 5/below, 6/right,7/above right}
    \fill[shift=(A.corner \i)] circle (1mm) node[\j]{$V_\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for showing another way to Rome, but sorry, a codeblock without any explanation doesn't help me understand the functioning of `\node` and `\coordinate` with `foreach`.  besides, i don't want to hard code the relative position of the text labels around the dots.  you see me writing `pin={\dTheta*\k}:{$V_{\k}$}` to calculate a suitable position to place the label---looking back, `pin` there should be replaced by `label` since I'm not using `pin edge`.  In your figure, the bottom two vertices V₄ and V₅ are too close to the black circular dots above them.